# Databinding updating with outdated values

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am not understanding the following 4 points about databinding. Not sure if i get unexpected results (outdated data in code behind), or if this is just a result of me misunderstanding how things work.

1. Bound data to a textbox updates when i leave the textbox. What event
   EXACTLY does this? LostFocus?
2. When using the now changed data in code behind
   it seems to still use the OLD data. Why is this happening? Could
   point 3 be the reason?
3. After the textbox updates i did a test and set datacontext
   to nothing and reaplied datacontext to the same scource. The values
   shown are the values before i edited them. Why did they show up after editing, but
   returned to the old values after rebinding?
4. After changing the values for the second time it seems
   like code behind uses the data after my first change. Rebinding like
   in point 3 leads to the same result (value after first change,
   second change ignored). Seems like code behind is always one update behind, can i change this?

Anyone able to explain why this happens?

**Desired behavior:**

I want the people count to update when I edit the housing count. Preferable on the fly, but after losing focus is fine. When losing focus the value for isle ID 0 should be the right one tho, and not the outdated value.

**For easier understanding**, a picture with 3 screens and related code samples.

http://www.mathematik-lehramtsstudium.de/BindingExample.jpg

**My class:**

```
//class for isles
public class isle : INotifyPropertyChanged
{        
    //Dummyvariables,...
    private int _intBauer;
    private int _intBauerBev;        

    //variables
    public int intIsleID { set; get; }      //isle ID
    public string strName { set; get; }     //isle name

    public int intBauer                     //housing count
    {       
      set 
      { 
         this._intBauer = value; 
         NotifyPropertyChanged("intBauer"); NotifyPropertyChanged("intBauerBev"); 
      } 
      get 
      { 
         return _intBauer; 
      } 
    }       
    public int intBauerBev                  //each house hosts 8 people
    { 
        set { this._intBauerBev = value;} 
        get { return intBauer * 8; } 
    }       

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

}
```

**LostFocus-Event for updating the right side oft he page**

```
    private void textboxHäuser_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {           
        //Gesamtzahl neu berechnen
        listIsles[0].intBauer = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            listIsles[0].intBauer += listIsles[i].intBauer;
        }
        //hard refresh DataContext, since it does not seem to update itself
        //leaving these two lines out of my code changes nothing tho, as expected 
        gridInfoGesamt.DataContext = "";
        gridInfoGesamt.DataContext = listIsles[0];
    }
```

Comment: You can read all about the answer to question 1 [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754356%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  
  
  
If your UI isn't updating your view model then there is something wrong with the bindings. Post your XAML. If your UI *is* updating your view model then it's obviously much easier to react to it in your properties' setters or, failing that for some reason, by handling your view model's PropertyChanged event.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I seem to have found the right pages and fixed my own issue while you where typing. Your link to Question 1 does explain this in more detail tho and i will read trough it a few times to make sure i don't fall for this trap again in the future. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue i was facing is the order in which events get fired in this case. Or more accurate: Two things happening at once.

TextBox uses the "LostFocus"-Event to update the property, same as the event i used to update my other TextBox controls. Since both fired at once i used the "outdated" data for calculations, therefore it looked like my UI lagged one step behind on one side.

To fix this i simply had to change the way my TextBox updates the property, by doing my binding like this in XAML:

```
Text="{Binding intBauer, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Now the property is updated instantly, before "LostFocus" and even before "TextChanged".
This also opens the possibility to update the UI as the user changes values and not only after he is finished. Much cleaner and better looking.